# tooltip reading from function using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have two functions where i read the tool-tip display values and it was not showing proper tool-tips, When i place the mouse over. It throws

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

function addurlPoints(resultDataset) {
    var pointOptions = {
            name : resultDataset.columnValues.id,
            composition: {                      
                '<spring:message code="reports.seriesname.somethin"/>': resultDataset.columnValues.id,
                '<spring:message code="reports.seriesname.somedata"/>': resultDataset.columnValues.sudo,
                '<spring:message code="reports.seriesname.ids"/>': resultDataset.columnValues.count,
                '<spring:message code="reports.seriesname.date"/>': resultDataset.columnValues.mindate,
                '<spring:message code="reports.seriesname.time"/>': resultDataset.columnValues.maxdate
                }
    }
    barchart.series[0].addPoint(pointOptions, false);
}
```

My tool-tip was written

```
tooltip: {
    style : { 
        width: 200
    },
    shared: false,
    formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br/><br/>'; 
        $.each(this.point.options.composition, function(name, value) {
            s += '<b>' + name + ':</b> ' + value + '<br>';
        });
        return s;
    }                            
}
```

Can any one help how can i read tooltip data from this function?

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/0mLa0yd5/3/ - I guess you have one (or more) points which don't contain `composition` property.